# Структура данных для хранения callbackов

Tags: c++, c++17

Мне нужна структура данных, которая каждой строке будет ставить в соответствие некоторую callback-функцию. Эта структура будет инициализироваться извне класса с помощью лямбд. Какую структуру данных лучше использовать, если сигнатуры функций **могут быть разными**?

Нужно такое поведение:

```
map["gui_ok_button"] = [&](){
   data.apply();
};
map["gui_close_button"] = [&](int close_code){
   data.close(close_code);
};
```

Comment: А как вы собираетесь потом вызывать функции с разными сигнатурами?...

Comment: Сигнатуры вообще любые или известен их набор?

Comment: @Harry `map["gui_ok_button"]()` и `map["gui_close_button"](0)` соответственно

Comment: @Cerbo ну на данный момент ограничены `(void(void), void(int), void(std::string))`, но может быть в будущем понадобится добавить какой-то новый тип

Comment: Откуда вы будете знать, что gui_close_button - с int, а gui_ok_button - пустая? Вы собираетесь где-то хранить эту информацию? Где, как?

Comment: @Harry при нажатии кнопки класс UI получает событие и отсылает его обработчику, он знает, что если нажата определенная кнопка, то надо передать определенные параметры

Comment: @Harry если например был нажат radiobutton, то его `int` индекс и т.п.

Comment: @Harry вызывает обработчик с помощью вот этой структуры как раз

Comment: Покажите пример [псевдо]кода. Без этого я не понимаю, как вы хотите это делать. Считаем, что вы реально можете хранить в некоем типе `func` ваши разнообразные функции. Итак, у вас есть `map<string,func> m`. Есть `string s`. Как вы вызываете `m[s]....` - что вместо троеточий?

Comment: @Harry ну я же написал `()` или  `(42)` или `("text")`

Comment: @Harry в зависимости от того, какая кнопка нажата

Comment: Не хотите писать код - не надо, дело ваше. Мое - не отвечать на вопрос без получения от вас ясного ответа. Удачи в хождении туда, не знаете куда, в поисках того, не знаете чего...

Comment: @Harry я же ответил на вопрос что вместо троеточий... 2 раза

Comment: Я просил привести **код**. Если я вам на ваш исходный вопрос отвечу - храните как-нибудь, потом вызывайте как хотите - вы это сочтете ответом на ваш вопрос? Последний раз - **код**. В указанных выше предположениях.

Comment: @Harry `m[s]();`, `m[s](42);`, `m[s]("text");`

Comment: Так ЧТО ИМЕННО? m[s]();, m[s](42); или m[s]("text");? Или вы планируете писать соплю `if (s==...) m[s](); else if (s == ...) m[s](42); else if...`? Тогда вам нафиг не нужна эта `map`.

Comment: @Harry так у меня это вызывается в методе обработки определённой кнопки. Этим сторонняя библиотека занимается. Если была нажата определённая кнопка, то вызывается определённая функция, которая относится к этой кнопке. То есть я знаю, что такое `s` в функции и какие параметры соответственно передавать

Comment: А нельзя сделать отдельные map'ы для callback'ов с разными наборами параметров? Тогда можно было бы использовать `std::function`.

Comment: [схожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45715219/6944845)

Answer (score 4):

Новые возможности Си++17 вам помогут. Могу предложить реализация на `std::variant`:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

// здесь должны быть перечислены варианты
// всех сигнатур
using Callback = std::variant
<
      std::function<void(void)>
    , std::function<void(int)>
    , std::function<void(const std::string&)>
>;

using CallbackMap = std::map<std::string, Callback>;
```

Далее главная идея решения, функция вызова:

```
// Эта перегрузка нужна для обработки неверных вызовов
// статическая проверка пока не приходит на ум.
template<typename F, typename ...A>
void DoCall(F&&, A&&...)
{
    throw std::bad_variant_access();
}

// Нужно для каждой варианта сигнатуры определить перегрузку для проброски 
// аргументов. Выглядит коряво, тут можно автоматизировать.
void DoCall(std::function<void(void)> & f)
{
    f();
}

void DoCall(std::function<void(int)> & f, int arg)
{
    f(arg);
}

void DoCall(std::function<void(const std::string&)> & f, const std::string & arg)
{
    f(arg);
}

// Собственно вызов калбека
template<typename ...A>
void Dispatch(const Callback & callback, A&& ...args)
{        
    // здесь лямбда нужна чтобы захватить args и передать в DoCall, 
    // все из-за того что std::visit не предусматривает проброс
    // аргументов в посетителя (здесь в нашу лямбду)
    std::visit
    (
        [&args...](auto && func) -> void
        {
            DoCall(func, std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }
      , callback
    );
}
```

Использовать это вот так как-то:

```
void TestCallbackMap()
{
    auto cm = CallbackMap();
    cm["foo"] = [](void) -> void
    {
        std::cout << "call: foo" << std::endl;
    };

    cm["bar"] = [](int arg) -> void
    {
        std::cout << "call: bar " << arg << std::endl;
    };

    cm["baz"] = [](const std::string & msg) -> void
    {
        std::cout << "call: baz " << msg << std::endl;
    };

    Dispatch(cm["baz"], std::string("hello world"));
}
```

Comment: Альтернативный вариант: Можно хранить в map'е `std::function<void(std::variant<Params1, Params2, ...>)>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Такой `function` не будет приводится к конкретным указателям на функции, у них же не варианты в аргументах, а автоматом они не приведутся.

Comment: У меня создалось впечатление, что автор сам пишет callback'и, и может их менять. Если нет, тогда действительно не подойдет.