# Контейнер функций с переменным числом аргументов

Tags: c++

Как объявить вектор из функций, принимающих переменное число аргументов?

Что-то типа такого нужно:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::vector<std::function<void(Args...)>> vector;
```

Comment: Боюсь что никак. Уже в точке конверсии пользовательского объекта в std::function компилятор должен проверить существование подходящего operator(). Но типы, необходимые для проверки будут известны только в точке вызова функции... попробуйте сформулировать задачу более высокого уровня, возможно, подскажем другое решение.

Comment: Можете рассказать, что собираетесь делать с подобным контейнером?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat контейнер для коллбеков, которые срабатывают по нажатию кнопок в пользовательском интерфейсе

Comment: @HolyBlackCat разные кнопки - разные действия - разные параметры

Comment: Можно использовать std::bind, и хранить в векторе std::function<void()>, но параметры нужно будет знать уже тогда когда вы добавляете результат std::bind в вектор.

Comment: Не понимаю. Как у колбеков разных кнопок могут быть разные параметры? Разве они не должны получать одинаковый набор входных данных (скажем, время клика, коордианты мыши и т.п.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat так устроена программа, для кнопки "Добавить элемент" нужно знать на какой мы сейчас строке списка (чтобы добавить в это место именно), а для кнопки "Вывести все элементы" этого не нужно, например

Comment: А в каком месте хранится переменная с номером текущей строки в списке? Скажем, если это глобальная переменная, или поле глобального объекта, вы могли бы обратиться к ней напрямую, не передавая ее в параметре.

Comment: Я нашёл, пролистал 15 страничек назад, но нашёл!!!  [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/910276/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-callback%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Велосипед, критика приветствуется.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using func_t = std::function<void()>;


void foo(const int& x, double d){
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << " " << x << " " << d << std::endl;
}
void bar(const int& x){
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " " << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<func_t > functions;
    int x = 5;
    functions.push_back(std::bind(foo, x, 2.0));
    functions.push_back(std::bind(bar, std::cref(x)));
    for (const auto& f: functions){
        f();
    }
    x = 20;
    for (const auto& f: functions){
        f();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
foo 5 2
bar 5
foo 5 2
bar 20
```

Comment: Но так я не смогу вызывать функции с разными параметрами

Comment: @qwerty Цитата из моего комментария к вопросу: "но параметры нужно будет знать уже тогда когда вы добавляете результат std::bind в вектор". Это пример исходя из того что вы хотите использовать std::function. Указатели на фукнции (с сигнатурой void* func(void*) ) возможно смогут вам помочь.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Ответ не отвечает на поставленный вопрос. Автор вопроса с этим согласен. Но ответ внезапно отмечен как "принятый". Что это?

Comment: @AnT я тоже удивился. А кто-нибудь может снять пометку принятого ответа кроме автора вопроса? Я там в комментарии к вопросу оставил ссылку на похожий вопрос. Или лучше удалить ответ?

Comment: @vegorov Меня тоже это удивило. Может автор после вашего комментария понял, что ему это подойдет... А удалить ответ вы скорее всего не сможете, из-за галки. И галку кроме автора тоже никому не снять.

Comment: @qwerty призываем Вас обратно. Снимите галочку или поясните почему вы её поставили - а то непонятно чё-то, всем включая меня =)